# MVC App works in IIS 7, does not work in Cassini (IIS 7, too)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, cassini

i have a mixed app (asp.net webforms, later mvc added) and it runs in iis 7 on vista but does not run on cassini on the same box and with the exact same files in the webroot. actually, webforms work as expected but all mvc routes are 404. what can i do to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Any solution yet? By chance are you using VS 2010 and just uninstalled VS 2008? I'm having the same issue where Cassini just won't serve up an MVC site, yet it works fine on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Phil's Haack Routing Debugger first.
You can find it there:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What is your project structure?

I remember having a solution that consisted of several different web forms applications - when I ran the solution in Cassini each application opened in a different port. Is it maybe so that when you test on Cassini, you click a url from the web forms app that is browsed on one port, and the MVC app can't be found because it's running on a different port?